# Python convert list to string in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have bunch of list and string like texts in the cell value of the pandas data frame. I am trying to convert list to string, I am able to convert list to string, but its splitting the string as well. How do I only apply this logic if the cell contains list [] in the particular column?

```
raw_data = {'Name': [['\'John Smith\''], ['\'Jane Doe\'']],
        'id': [['\'A1005\'','\'A1006\''], 'A200,A400,A500']}
dfRaw = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name','id'])
dfRaw['Name'] = dfRaw['Name'].astype(str)
```

Data

```
Name                    id
0   ["'John Smith'"]    ['A1005', 'A1006']
1   ["'Jane Doe'"]  A200,A400,A500
```

Need output like this:

```
    Name                id
0   ["'John Smith'"]    'A1005','A1006'
1   ["'Jane Doe'"]      A200,A400,A500
```

But the code below is splitting string cell values too.

```
dfRaw['id'] = dfRaw['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(i) for i in x]))

Name                     id
0   ["'John Smith'"]    'A1005','A1006'
1   ["'Jane Doe'"]  A,2,0,0,,,A,4,0,0,,,A,5,0,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a new list with the rows in `id` joining those entries that are lists using [`string.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).
You can check if an entry is a `list` using [`isinstance`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html):

```
df['id'] = [','.join(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in df['id']]
```

**Output**

```
       Name                    id
0  ['John Smith']          A1005,A1006
1    ['Jane Doe']        A200,A400,A500
```